# Finding the generator of a kernel

Tags: abstract-algebra

Take a Ring Homomorphism $\phi: \mathbb{C}[x,y]\to \mathbb{C} [t]$. I have an element in the kernel based on how it is defined. I need to find the generator of the ideal, and am told to do it by showing kernel = $I$, I am not sure why it is this equality that I need to show?

I can use the 1st Isomorphism Theorm to say 
$\mathbb{C}$ [x,y] mod $I \to \ \mathbb{C} [t]$, which is perhaps why it we can use the ker = $I$ since by definition of mod, this is what goes to zero.

Comment: Please use MathJax. Is “C” supposed to be $\mathbb{C}$, the complex numbers?

Comment: Note that $\mathbb{F}[x,y]$ is **not** a Principal Ideal Domain even when $\mathbb{F}$ is a field: $(x,y)$ is not a principal ideal. It is a UFD, but not a PID.

Comment: yes, it is $\mathbb{C}$ . Edited.

Comment: I’ve gone ahead and fixed it full. Note that $I$ is not “a principal domain”; presumably you mean “a principal ideal”. And as noted, that does not work in the context you are writing! $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ is **not** a PID. It *is* a UFD, so you could try looking at the factors of your element; but even then, that isn’t going to necessarily give you the kernel. You’re going to have to (i) be more specific; and (ii) be accurate, because what you say above does not seem to make a lot of sense (perhaps when trying to go general, you messed up?)

Comment: Yes, I messed up. I mean I = Ker (phi), where I is principal, ie, one generator

Comment: Okay, but it is still wrong: you cannot know ahead of time that $I$ is a principal ideal “because $\mathbb{C}$ is a field” if your domain is $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$; while it is true that for a field $\mathbb{F}$ the ring of polynomials in one variable $\mathbb{F}[x]$ is a Principal Ideal Domain, that is **not** true for the ring of polynomials in more than one variable.

Comment: ok. Hopefully this is clarified now. It is the equality that I am confused on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105822/discussion-between-epsilonolispe-and-arturo-magidin).

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What is $\phi$? We can help you find the kernel once we know what the map is. Without knowing $\phi$ I'm not sure how helpful we can be

Comment: x -> t+1 , y -> t^3-1